# Diagonalizing a matrix $A$ by diagonalizing $\alpha A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable.

For practical reasons it is sometimes for convenient to work with
$\alpha A$ instead of A ($\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$),

For example if
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\
-\frac{1}{8} & \frac{3}{4}
\end{pmatrix}$$ then working with $$8A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 8\\
-1 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$$ can be more convenient.

If I wish to find $P,D$ s.t. $P^{-1}AP=D$ then I can do so by calculating
the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $A$.

**My question is this:** If I work with $B=\alpha A$ and find the eigenvectors
and eigenvalues of $B$ then I have it that the same $P$ will diagonalize
$A$ and $B$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are the eigenvalues of $A$
multiplied by $\alpha$ ?

My reasoning is that if $Av=\lambda v$ then $\alpha Av=\alpha\lambda v$
so it's the same $v$ but the eigenvalue of $B$ is $\alpha\lambda$, am I correct ?

Comment: You had better not take $\alpha=0$. But otherwise, its fine.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you said is correct.